# trying to open the specific tab for a popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page link where i had to click and that passes the value of the link as:

```
link.html?action=paid#mypayments-3
```

and the link.html has `tabs` as: they are jquery UI tabs

```
<a href="#payments-3">Paid</a>
<a href="#payments-1">Overpaid</a>
<a href="#payments-2">Pending</a>
```

its not going to that section, how can i force it to go to that tab, Am i missing anything

Comment: Try using a "_" instead of a "-"

Comment: You used `mypayments` in the first url but `payments` in the html